# Got `Incompatible library version` error when executing `pandoc` command

Tags: pandoc, dylib, dyld

When I execute `pandoc f.md --pdf-engine=xelatex -o f.pdf`, I get the following error which was triggered by other commands. I search the issue on the web but get nothing useful. Can someone help me?

> dyld: Library not loaded:
> /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libGIF.dylib
> Referenced from:
> /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/ImageIO
> Reason: Incompatible library version: ImageIO requires version 1.0.0
> or later, but libGIF.dylib provides version 0.0.0 dyld: Library not
> loaded:
> /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libGIF.dylib
> Referenced from:
> /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/ImageIO
> Reason: Incompatible library version: ImageIO requires version 1.0.0
> or later, but libGIF.dylib provides version 0.0.0 Error producing PDF.

Comment: export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH="/System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/Resources:/usr/local/lib"